# Filtering down SQL To one value?

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I'm writing a query for SAP B1,using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I am wanting to return the "MIN" DocDate, but show the field "ShipDate" alongside it, with only one result...

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode, 
    T3.ShipDate AS 'Next Date',
    MIN(T3.DocDate) AS 'OrderDate'
FROM OITM T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN POR1 T3 ON T0.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode

WHERE T3.LineStatus = 'O' AND T3.ShipDate > GETDATE()

Group By T0.Itemcode, T3.ShipDate
```

This returns the following results;

| ItemCode | ShipDate | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VT3021026 | 2021-05-14 | 2021-05-04 |
| VT3021026 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-05-10 |

This is an example of what one single item is returning, however I want to return only one value for each item. Almost like a "TOP 1" for each individual item. (obviously top 1 won't work in the overall select clause because it will be required to produce a list of multiple items)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this code will solve the problem.

```
DECLARE @date datetime2 = GETDATE();

WITH T(ItemCode, OrderDate) AS
(
    SELECT 
        T0.ItemCode, 
        MIN(T3.DocDate) AS 'OrderDate'
    FROM OITM T0
        LEFT JOIN POR1 T3 
            ON T0.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode
    WHERE T3.LineStatus = 'O' 
        AND T3.ShipDate > @date
    GROUP BY T0.Itemcode, T3.ShipDate
)
SELECT T.ItemCode, 
    T4.ShipDate AS 'Next Date',
    T.OrderDate
FROM T
    LEFT JOIN POR1 T4
        ON T.[OrderDate] = T4.DocDate
         AND T.ItemCode = t4.ItemCode;
```

Comment: Alexey, you can't join back on the orderdate. you must join back on the order number which the question did not provide.

Comment: I hurried and missed the order in the join.